# AWK replace NULL column values with column values of previous row

Tags: bash, awk, replace

I have a sample file as following:

```
cat sample.txt

HOST dev@opulex.com
PORT 1066
DATABASE ORACLE_1
SCHEMA DEPT.*;
SCHEMA EMP.*;
DATABASE ORACLE_2
SCHEMA JOB.*;
```

For the content in the above sample file, I would like to print only the columns next to HOST/PORT/DATABASE/SCHEMA. So, I could achieve that as following:

```
cat sample.txt | awk 'tolower($0)~/^host|^port|^database|^schema/{printf "%s",$2 OFS;}' | awk -v RS=';' -v ORS=';\n' 'NF'

dev@opulex.com 1066 ORACLE_1 DEPT.*;
 EMP.*;
 ORACLE_2 JOB.*;
```

Assuming that last column in every record ends with semi-colon `(;)`, How can I use AWK to replace NULL column values with the column values of previous row as following:

```
 dev@opulex.com 1066 ORACLE_1 DEPT.*;
 dev@opulex.com 1066 ORACLE_1 EMP.*;
 dev@opulex.com 1066 ORACLE_2 JOB.*;
```

Thanks in Advance.!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have this data:

```
cat file

dev@opulex.com 1066 ORACLE_1 DEPT.*;
 EMP.*;
 ORACLE_2 JOB.*;
```

Using awk you can do:

```
awk 'NF==1{print c1, c2, c3, $1; next}
     NF==2{print c1, c2, $1, $2; next}
     {c1=$1; c2=$2; c3=$3} 1' file
```

**Output:**

```
dev@opulex.com 1066 ORACLE_1 DEPT.*;
dev@opulex.com 1066 ORACLE_1 EMP.*;
dev@opulex.com 1066 ORACLE_2 JOB.*;
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for the reply. Can you please elaborate the logic?

Comment: When there is only one cell value `NF==1` then we use previously saved values in `c1,c2,c3` variables. When there are two cell value `NF==2` then we use previously saved values in `c1,c2` variables. Finally when we have all the columns available then we save column values in `c1,c2,c3` variables (to be used later).

Comment: Thank you for the explanation.

Comment: `$> cat sample2.txt
HOST dev@opulex.com
PORT 1066
DATABASE ORACLE_1
SCHEMA DEPT.*;
SCHEMA EMP.*;
DATABASE ORACLE_2
SCHEMA JOB.*;
SCHEMA SALARY.*;`

`$> cat sample2.txt | awk 'tolower($0)~/^host|^port|^database|^schema/{printf "%s",$2 OFS;}' | awk -v RS=';' -v ORS=';\n' 'NF' |
awk 'NF==1{print c1, c2, c3, $1; next} NF==2{print c1, c2, $1, $2; next} {c1=$1; c2=$2; c3=$3} 1' | sed 's|^[[:blank:]]*||g; s|\;$||g'>
dev@opulex.com 1066 ORACLE_1 DEPT.*
dev@opulex.com 1066 ORACLE_1 EMP.*
dev@opulex.com 1066 ORACLE_2 JOB.*
dev@opulex.com 1066 ORACLE_1 SALARY.*`

Comment: But expected is
`dev@opulex.com 1066 ORACLE_1 DEPT.*
dev@opulex.com 1066 ORACLE_1 EMP.*
dev@opulex.com 1066 ORACLE_2 JOB.*
dev@opulex.com 1066 ORACLE_2 SALARY.*`

Comment: Near impossible to understand any data from comments. Besides your commands show that you're doing something more than my suggested awk command as well. I think it would be better to create a new question with all relevant details and we'll make sure to help you out fast.

Comment: Sorry about that @anubhava.. I created a new question here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36342300/awk-replace-null-column-values-with-column-values-of-previous-row-continuation

Answer (score 0):

another `awk` alternative

```
$ rev file | 
  awk 'NF>1{c2=$2?$2:c2; c3=$3?$3:c3; c4=$4?$4:c4}
           {print $1,c2,c3,c4}' | 
  rev

dev@opulex.com 1066 ORACLE_1 DEPT.*;
dev@opulex.com 1066 ORACLE_1 EMP.*;
dev@opulex.com 1066 ORACLE_2 JOB.*;
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing
additional context regarding _why_ and/or _how_ it answers
the question would significantly improve its long-term
value.  Please [edit] your answer to add some explanation.