# AWK replace NULL column values with column values of previous row (continuation)

Tags: bash, awk, replace

This post is an amendment to my question I asked earlier [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36318857/awk-replace-null-column-values-with-column-values-of-previous-row/36319031?noredirect=1#comment60305930_36319031).

Say I have below sample file:

```
cat sample2.txt
HOST dev@opulex.com
PORT 1066
DATABASE ORACLE_1
SCHEMA DEPT.*;
SCHEMA EMP.*;
DATABASE ORACLE_2
SCHEMA JOB.*;
SCHEMA SALARY.*;
HOST orl@opulex.com
PORT 89
DATABASE MYSQL_1
SCHEMA PURCHASE.*;
DATABASE MYSQL_2
SCHEMA PRICE.*;
SCHEMA PRODUCT.*;
```

For the content in the above file, I would like to print only the columns next to HOST/PORT/DATABASE/SCHEMA and at the same time assuming that the last column in every row ends with semicolon, I would like to replace the missing column values with the column values of previous row.

@anubhava helped me to achieve something close to it as following in my [previous post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36318857/awk-replace-null-column-values-with-column-values-of-previous-row/36319031?noredirect=1#comment60305930_36319031).:

```
cat sample2.txt | awk 'tolower($0)~/^host|^port|^database|^schema/{printf "%s",$2 OFS;}' | awk -v RS=';' -v ORS=';\n' 'NF' | awk 'NF==1{print c1, c2, c3, $1; next} NF==2{print c1, c2, $1, $2; next} {c1=$1; c2=$2; c3=$3} 1' | sed 's|^[[:blank:]]*||g; s|\;$||g'
    dev@opulex.com 1066 ORACLE_1 DEPT.*
    dev@opulex.com 1066 ORACLE_1 EMP.*
    dev@opulex.com 1066 ORACLE_2 JOB.*
    dev@opulex.com 1066 ORACLE_1 SALARY.*
    orl@opulex.com 89 MYSQL_1 PURCHASE.*
    orl@opulex.com 89 MYSQL_2 PRICE.*
    orl@opulex.com 89 MYSQL_1 PRODUCT.*
```

But I am expecting it to be as following

```
dev@opulex.com 1066 ORACLE_1 DEPT.*
dev@opulex.com 1066 ORACLE_1 EMP.*
dev@opulex.com 1066 ORACLE_2 JOB.*
dev@opulex.com 1066 ORACLE_2 SALARY.*
orl@opulex.com 89 MYSQL_1 PURCHASE.*
orl@opulex.com 89 MYSQL_2 PRICE.*
orl@opulex.com 89 MYSQL_2 PRODUCT.*
```

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use this **single awk** command to get your output:

```
awk '{sub(/;$/, "")} $1=="HOST"{host=$2} $1=="PORT"{port=$2} $1=="DATABASE"{db=$2}
      $1=="SCHEMA"{print host, port, db, $2}' sample2.txt

dev@opulex.com 1066 ORACLE_1 DEPT.*
dev@opulex.com 1066 ORACLE_1 EMP.*
dev@opulex.com 1066 ORACLE_2 JOB.*
dev@opulex.com 1066 ORACLE_2 SALARY.*
orl@opulex.com 89 MYSQL_1 PURCHASE.*
orl@opulex.com 89 MYSQL_2 PRICE.*
orl@opulex.com 89 MYSQL_2 PRODUCT.*
```

**Explanation:**

- `sub` function is removing trailing `;` from each line
- When `$1=="HOST"` we store 2nd column in a variable `host`
- When `$1=="PORT"` we store 2nd column in a variable `port`
- When `$1=="DATABASE"` we store 2nd column in a variable `db`
- When `$1=="SCHEMA"` we print `host, port, db, 2nd column`

Comment: Awesome.. Thank you! But can you please explain the logic here.. so that people like me can learn.. :)

Comment: I've added it in my answer.

Answer (score 2):

```
$ awk '{a[$1]=$2} sub(/;/,""){print a["HOST"], a["PORT"], a["DATABASE"], $2}' file
dev@opulex.com 1066 ORACLE_1 DEPT.*
dev@opulex.com 1066 ORACLE_1 EMP.*
dev@opulex.com 1066 ORACLE_2 JOB.*
dev@opulex.com 1066 ORACLE_2 SALARY.*
orl@opulex.com 89 MYSQL_1 PURCHASE.*
orl@opulex.com 89 MYSQL_2 PRICE.*
orl@opulex.com 89 MYSQL_2 PRODUCT.*
```